# using R code on windows and unix with relative symlinks

Tags: r, windows, unix, symlink

I have a mapped drive from a *nix system on my windows 7 machine. I would like to work on code from work on my home computer. The problem is the directory structure at work has a bunch of symlinks which the R code references. Windows is unable to see those symlinks and so the entire thing crashes. Is there a way to make Windows/R recognize these links? The reason I say Windows/R is because WinSCP *is* able to see these links.

Comment: Your title says *relative* symlinks but you do not mention it in the question. Can you confirm those symlinks are relative and not absolute? Because making them relative is the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: i may be confusing terminology: my unix system consists of several mounts. my simlink in `/a/b/c/mylink` points to `/x/y/z/myfolder`. when i map the `/a/b/c/` to `z:\` in windows, for example, all the other stuff is there but `mylink` isn't

Comment: when i said relative in the question, i meant that i was attempting to access my link in R through `../mylink` syntax

Comment: Well then instead of creating your symlink using an absolute path `cd a/b/c; ln -sf /x/y/z/myfolder mylink`, you should be using a relative path: `ln -sf ../../../x/y/z/myfolder mylink`. I can post it as an answer if you can confirm this works.

Comment: are you available to chat? i think we are speaking past each other right now and i would appreciate you rhelp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65732/discussion-between-alex-and-flodel).